# AndEngine - Checking for Overlap with Sprite or Physics Body?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm trying to make it so when a sprite which is attached to a physics body overlaps another sprite on the level something happens. The second sprite is NOT attached to a physics body.

More specifically when the two sprites are overlapping I want the game to constantly check to see if the distance between the centers of the sprites is less than a certain amount or not. Then if the distance is small enough something will happen.

I'm trying to use collision checking as a way of optimizing the game so it doesn't have to constantly check distances between every single object of type A and B even if they're not even close. It will only check the distance when they're close enough to be overlapping.

Now what I am wondering is how can I do this? Is there a way to check collisions between sprites as part of AndEngine? Or would it be easier to attach a physics body to the second object also and then just use physics collision detection? But then if I do that can I make it so the collision will be detected but they won't actually physically "collide"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see [CollisionDetectionExample.java](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/CollisionDetectionExample.java). I suggest you download the whole examples package, it is very useful in the absence of any documentation for AndEngine. Please note that collision detection is not pixel perfect, so it will still detect collisions of transparent parts of the Sprites. There is [a library](https://github.com/m5/andengine-pixel-perfect) for that, but I am afraid it is outdated.

Comment: I see from the example that it makes a new UpdateHandler() and then overrides the onUpdate() method. So would it be better to put all my time-based game logic into this one UpdateHandler or should I be using multiple ones for different events?

Comment: I don't think the performance penalty for using multiple UpdateHandlers really matters. Merging UpdateHandler could help you achieve better performance if you could reuse some things that are now created twice because of the separation. I could be wrong though, so I suggest you write a little test for that to be sure.